# react(es6) build by webpack has an Uncaught TypeError in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have used the react.js in my project.I write react class by es6 syntax. And I build my react component with webpack, the bundle.js runs well but I found that I just can not run any other js after the bundle.js in my browser. When I run "var a = 0" in the console of browser, I got an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toString' of function 'function bound(var_args)
    {
        return InjectedScriptHost.callFunction(func, thisObject, concat(args, sl...<omitted>... }'
```

My version infos:

babel:6.5.2

react:0.14.5

webpack:1.12.14

My webpack config is:

```
 module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.react\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        })
    ]
```

I wanna if anyone has met some problems like this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your babel loader to test for `/\.react\.js$/` because that will match on the react library itself, and that's not what you're going for.   Instead, you want the loader to test for YOUR application files matching `/\.jsx?$/` (assuming your file extensions are .jsx, which they should be).   Assuming the rest of your webpack configuration is good, this should work.

If you'd like me to explain further, let me know.

Comment: You do tell me a mistake I made, the /\.react\.js$/ .   I change the application files from xxxx.react.js  to xxxx.blog.js, and change the webpack.config and file import, but the problem still.